# ViewGroup.java AddViewInner issue

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity

i keep getting following errors, it's basically same error but keeps occuring on different lines

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3883)
>
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4312)
>
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4310)

Things i have tried :-

- while adding any fragment i add this code in onCreateView

  ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_carpool_layout, container, false);
  return view;

  and then inflate the view
- While inflating layouts / views in adapter also i make sure the view is removed from parent view

I am not sure what is causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try double checking how you are inflating the view.

There are two possible ways:

1. Passing the parent to the inflater:

   ```
   LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout, this, true);
   ```
2. Keep the view without the parent:

   ```
   LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
   ```

When using the first method, you cannot call `addView()` with the `view` as parameter.

Using the second way, the view is not pinned to parent, therefore you can invoke `addView()`

Comment: i have edited the question, please check in case of fragments i am using view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_carpool_layout, container, false); as i dont have to do addView in onCreateView

Comment: Are you sure you are not adding the fragment twice?

Comment: Yes, as this happens with 2% of users only... i am not able to reproduce this on my testing devices. If fragment would have been added twice i would be able to reproduce error