# java.lang.IllegalStateException: at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner

Tags: android, android-fragments

App getting crash with following stack trace on some device with some OS version. I have tried some other suggestion none of them work. I don't know where exactly crash occur.

[ViewGroup.java AddViewInner issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641951/viewgroup-java-addviewinner-issue)

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 28
```

Always Inflating Layout like below for all screen:

```
if (mainView == null) {
     mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}
```

Committing Fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_in_left, R.anim.fragment_slide_out_left, R.anim.fragment_slide_in_right, R.anim.fragment_slide_out_right);
ft.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment, fragment.getTagText());
ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getTagText());
ft.commit();
```

Crash 1:

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner (ViewGroup.java:5008)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4833)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4773)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4746)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1466)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1784)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1852)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps (BackStackRecord.java:860)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2622)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2411)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2366)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2273)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run (FragmentManagerImpl.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:171)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6656)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:547)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Crash 2:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner (ViewGroup.java:5122)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4953)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4893)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4866)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1466)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1784)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1852)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps (BackStackRecord.java:860)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2622)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2411)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2366)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2273)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run (FragmentManagerImpl.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6940)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

How to fix this crash?

Comment: try with ft.add() insted of ft.replace()

Comment: @MilanPansuriya Thank you. Can you please explain how will it work?  I don't want to keep all the fragments to keep alive. That's why am replacing.

Answer (score 1):

Remove that null check and inflate view in `onCreateView`.

When you are returning old view `(mainView != null)` fragment tries to add it again to the view hierarchy. The exception is thrown as the old view already has a parent and cannot be added again.

source of ViewGroup.addViewInner:

```
    if (child.getParent() != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The specified child already has a parent. " +
                "You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.");
    }
```

Comment: So, Do i need to inflate the layout all the time? This crash happening on some devices only.

Comment: `FragmentManager` is in charge of deciding whether recreate your view hierarchy or not (or just detach and reattach it), you shouldn't cache it on your own. I believe that this is a reason of crashes.

Comment: Here am replacing fragment, which is same as calling 'removing fragment' by saving state of data in fragment and destroy the view.

Comment: Have you tried without that null check? How you create a `fragment` instance (that code is not posted)? Do you create new one or somehow reusing existing instances?

Comment: Yes. That was my earlier days code. Creating new one.

Comment: Am creating new one and there is no need of reusing the same fragments as per my business logic. Each fragment appear only once. I popup from backstack once pressed back button.